# jquery $variableName vs $(variableName)

Tags: jquery

```
var $myDiv = $("div#myDiv");//example 1
$myDiv.val(); //example 1

var myDiv = $("div#myDiv"); //example 2
$(myDiv).val(); //example 2
```

Is there any difference between example 1 and example 2 above?
Are both same as far as performance is concerned?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you understand that `$(...)` is a function call where `$` is the function, but the `$` in `$myDiv` is just part of a variable name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Now I see you've edited your code example yet again (for the 2nd or 3rd time) and the code now looks like this:

```
var $myDiv = $("div#myDiv");//example 1
$myDiv.val(); //example 1

var myDiv = $("div#myDiv"); //example 2
$(myDiv).val(); //example 2
```

In this case, the first example is more efficient because you are directly using the jQuery object you have already created.  In the second example, you are creating a new jQuery object from the first jQuery object which there is no reason to do.  So example 1 is recommended.  Example 2 will work, but is a wasteful and unnecessary.

Comment: @user979189 - OK, I removed most of my previous answer and wrote a new answer based on the code example you now have.  Please don't do what you just did - posting one code example and then changing it twice while people are writing answers - get the code example right before you post because it just wastes everyone's time to change the question while people are writing answers.  Hopefully the answer I have now addresses the code example you have now.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do `$(myDiv)` a second time in example 2 because it is already a jQuery object. `myDiv.val()` is enough. When you take off the $(), the examples do exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Example 2 is a tiny bit slower, because you're wrapping a jquery instance in just another jquery instance (what is the point of doing that?) - it works because jquery handles it right, but it does not make any sense.